# build range table from log table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, date-range

I have a log table that has 4 columns (`MainId`, `ChildId`, `UnixTime`, `IsStopped`).
I need to insert this data into a range-table. (`MainId`, `ChildId`, `StartUnixTime`, `StopUnixtime`)

The logic for a range to be created is as follows:

- The smallest `UnixTime` with `IsStopped` = 0 in the log table is always the first `StartUnixTime`  in the range-table.
- After this to build up ranges the condition is: If `IsStopped` = 1 then this is the end of a range and the next row with `IsStopped` = 0 is the start of a new range

Because `IsStopped` is not always set there a 2 more conditions:

- If the `MainId` changes from one row to another the row in which it was changed is the end of a range and this row is also the start of a new range.
- The same as for `MainId` applies to `ChildId`.

I have made a [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f682e/3).

We currently have a solution for this that includes a cursor. But this gets very slow as this table is around 30 million rows.

How can I do this without a cursor?

**UPDATE:**

As SqlFiddle does have problems today (i can't build any schema only get a xml error) I post the script here:

```
create function dbo.UnixToDate(@unixTime int) returns datetime
as begin
    return dateadd(s, @unixTime, '1970-01-01')
end
go

create table test (
    Id Int Primary Key Identity, 
    MainId int, 
    ChildId int, 
    UnixTime int, 
    IsStoppped bit
)
go

insert into test (MainId, ChildId, UnixTime, IsStopped) values
(1, 100, 1406028071, 0),
(1, 100, 1406028073, 0),
(1, 102, 1406028078, 0),
(1, 102, 1406028080, 0),
(1, 102, 1406028099, 0),
(1, 100, 1406028130, 0),
(1, 102, 1406028132, 0),
(1, 102, 1406028134, 0),
(1, 102, 1406028138, 0),
(1, 100, 1406028140, 0),
(1, 100, 1406028148, 1),
(1, 100, 1406028150, 0),
(2, 100, 1406028151, 0),
(2, 100, 1406028152, 1),
(2, 100, 1406028153, 1),
(1, 100, 1406028155, 0)
go

create table expected (
    MainId int,
    ChildId int,
    StartUnixTime int,
    StopUnixTime int
)
go

insert into expected(MainId, ChildId, StartUnixTime, StopUnixTime) values
(1, 100, 1406028071, 1406028078),
(1, 102, 1406028078, 1406028130),
(1, 100, 1406028130, 1406028132),
(1, 102, 1406028132, 1406028140),
(1, 100, 1406028140, 1406028148),
(1, 100, 1406028150, 1406028151),
(2, 100, 1406028151, 1406028152),
(1, 100, 1406028155, null)
go

select 
    MainId, 
    ChildId, 
    UnixTime, 
    dbo.UnixToDate(UnixTime), 
    IsStopped
from test
order by UnixTime asc
go

--excpected
select
    *
from excpected
order by StartUnixTime asc
```

**UPDATE:**

The requirements have changed and I'm now able to change the log table to always include a `IsStopped` column.
I update my question later today to include new sample data... i give the accepted answer to the solution which can create this range table in the lowest time.

Comment: Shoudn`t you have 1406028071 and 1406028073 as startunixtime,stopunixtime as the last range and not 1406028071 and 1406028078 in your fiddle?Since childid is changing after 1406028073?

Comment: thanks for your comment. The first range is from 1406028071 to 1406028078. I had a `order by StartUnixTime desc` and not `asc` in my sqlfiddle by accident...just changed it

Comment: Yes but you say that if the childid changes than you have a new range.Isnthe first range that with childid 100 and then follows the next range?

Comment: the row in which the ChildId changes is the end of the previous range and also the start of the new range

Comment: I`ll give it a try tomorrow if nobody answers.

Comment: Sorry I had exam today.

Comment: no problem... i hope the exam went well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright,2 hours later here it is

```
WITH cte as(select MainId,ChildID,
    (CASE WHEN LEAD(MainId,1,0) OVER(ORDER BY UnixTime)<>MainId THEN LEAD(UnixTime,1,0) OVER(ORDER BY UnixTime) END) as mainIdbreak


from test
UNION
SELECT Top 1 MainId,ChildID,MIN(Unixtime) OVER (ORDER  BY UnixTime) FROM test WHERE IsStopped=0
UNION
SELECT MainId,ChildID, (CASE WHEN LEAD(ChildId,1,0) OVER(ORDER BY UnixTime)<>ChildId THEN LEAD(UnixTime,1,0) OVER(ORDER BY UnixTime) END) as childIdbreak
from test
UNION
SELECT
MainId,ChildID,(CASE WHEN LEAD(IsStopped,1,0) OVER(ORDER BY UnixTime)<>IsStopped THEN LEAD(UnixTime,1,0) OVER(ORDER BY UnixTime) END) as IsStoppedbreak
from test)
SELECT MainId,ChildID, mainIdbreak,LEAD(mainIdbreak,1,0) OVER(ORDER BY mainIdbreak) FROM cte Where mainIdbreak<>0



1   100 1406028071  1406028078
1   100 1406028078  1406028130
1   102 1406028130  1406028132
1   100 1406028132  1406028140
1   102 1406028140  1406028148
1   100 1406028148  1406028150
1   100 1406028150  1406028151
1   100 1406028151  1406028152
2   100 1406028152  1406028155
2   100 1406028155  0
```

I think your desired results are a bit off,the ending range doesn't repeat in the beginning range in some places.

Comment: thanks for your efforts. The child Id is off in some rows and the line with 1,100,1406028148,1406028150 and 2,100,1406028152,1406028155 are not required. I will try to work something out from your script. thanks again

Comment: @caribertl So it can only start a range if istopped is 0 but not 1?

Comment: yes, if there are multiple isStopped=1 and then there is somewhere a isStopped=0 this is the start of a new range - the first isStopped =1 is always the end of a range ...unless of course the mainId/childId changes. sorry if i weren't clear enough

Comment: @caribertl I`ll tweak it again tomorrow,I have a few intuitions.Jusr curious as it is,is it faster than cursor?

Comment: this would be very helpful. I figured out in the meantime that if the 2nd Column in the 3rd query inside cte is change to "lead(ChildID) over (order by UnixTime)" instead of "ChildId" the ChildId Column is right in the result.

Comment: i haven't tested in the big table only in my sample data and here both solutions are almost instant. I can imagine that your solution right now isn't really faster because of the 4 querys to the table without where clauses. But I can test this tomorow. I need to query this table by MainId or ChildId (with start -end time) so I think that when there is a way to include this in the 4 cte queries this would be a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

I can see why you'd have performance problems with a large number of rows.  Consider creating a table with unixTime/nextUnixTimeWhereIsStoppedEQ1 so you can limit the rows considered for your next stop time by however many rows there are until the next row with isStopped = 1, instead of querying all 30 million rows for the next match.

I can see why you'd use a cursor to figure out what to add to your log table.  Not using a cursor can sound appealing, but understand you're considering a lot of garbage rows for the end time instead of just the next few rows.  When your end points are sparsely populated, using set functions makes more sense.

Also understand your udf will significantly hinder your performance.  Make sure you're not calling it in your loop but just at the end to report your results.

I'm interpreting your requirements as:

```
start at min(unixtime) >> first_unixtime    
stop when 
     mainID <> mainid(first_unixtime) or 
     childID <> childid(first_unixtime) or 
     isstopped=1 or 
     eof    
  when isstopped=1, start on next row, else start on this row >> next_startunixtime
repeat with next_startunixtime
```

HTH

Comment: thank you for your input. my requirements have changed